# Xamarin.Forms: Let Picker show in title something else than what has been picked

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

This sounds like a stupid idea, but hear me out:

My custom picker has a list with the top item being: "no filtering". If someone picks this item, I dont want the picker to say "no filtering" as it does atm, I want it to display its title again which is "region".

I mean, it does this from the beginning, only when you change the list to something else, it always shows what has been picked (which is fine) but in this one case, I want it to display "Region" again and not just "no filtering" (since it is a picker to chose a certain region.

I tried to set the picker to its title again:

```
            picker_subcat1_mainmenu.Title = "Region";
```

But this doenst change anything, since the title hasnt changed, only what is displayed has.

Can u help me out here?

THank you!

Answer (score 0):

Xamarin.Forms picker has it's default value which is -1 when nothing selected. Picker's items start from 0. So as far as i got your problem, here is one solution which i'll suggest:

when pickers index change, an event called picker_SelectedIndexChanged fired. Change placeholder(Title) of picker when select "no filtering" which has 0 index in picker.

```
private void picker_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var picker = sender as Picker;
            if (picker.SelectedIndex == 0)
            {
               picker_subcat1_mainmenu.Title = "Region";
            }
            else{               
               return;
               //or set e.selectedItem  
            }
        }
```

Let me know if you have any query. Hope this will help you.

Thank you.

Comment: I did that, but it crashed the reload of the page saying the index of the array is out of bounds...

Comment: Can you show us your code so we can find better solution for you. Have you bind enum to picker or what ?